# JavaScript localStorage - Text input from Multiple User Cards

Tags: javascript, html, css, foreach, local-storage

## Please kindly let me know if this belongs in another thread.

I have a project involving user cards.

Objective:
1. add the ability to enter comments/tag in the provided text input for each user card.
2. save entered comments/tag using localStorage JavaScript.
3. saved comments/tag to be displayed in the user card where comments/tag was entered.
   eg.
   3 user cards, comments/tag entered on cards 1 & 3 only, onload tags comments/tag should appear on cards 1 & 3 only and card 2 will show placeholder or blank.

Problem:
If I enter a comment/tag on card 1, onload it displays as expected on card 1.

when comments/tags are entered on cards 2 or 3, onload comments/tag will appear on card 1 only, nothing on card where comments/tag were entered.

Am I forgetting something when i do forEach (or am i misusing it all together).
Appreciate any help/guidance, Im sorry Im new to JavaScript.

**prefer plain JavaScript code samples if possible.

My code link to CodePen - https://codepen.io/marcusnapoleon/pen/GRKzpeE

```js
//SAVE 
function saveTag(event) {
     var tagTerm = event.target.value;
    var tagTextInput = document.querySelectorAll("p.tagFilter");
     
     tagTextInput.forEach(function (cardTags) {
       
         localStorage.setItem("tag", tagTerm)       
         
     });       
  } 


//RETRIEVE
function show(event) {
      
  tagTextInput = document.querySelectorAll("p.tagFilter");
      tagTextInput.forEach(function (getTags) {
      var y = localStorage.getItem("tag");
        
      document.getElementById("name").innerHTML = y
        });
 }
```

```css
.card{
width: 300px;
border: 1px solid lightgrey;
padding: 5px 20px;
}
.container{
width: 60%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  padding: 100px 250px;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 
</head>
<body onload="show()"> 
  
      <div class="container">
            <div class="card">
            <h2>Name : User One</h2>
            <h2>Title : Job One</h2>
            Enter your name: <input id="tagInput" onkeyup="saveTag(event)"  type="text" placeholder="Comment here" >
            <b>TAG:</b><p class="tagFilter" id="name">tag goes here</p>
            <input onclick="clear()" type="button" value="CLEAR" />
            </div>
           
            <div class="card">
            <h2>Name : User Two</h2>
            <h2>Title : Job Two</h2>
            Enter your name: <input id="tagInput" onkeyup="saveTag(event)"  type="text" placeholder="Comment here" >
            <b>TAG:</b><p class="tagFilter" id="name">tag goes here</p>
            <input onclick="clear()" type="button" value="CLEAR" />
            </div>
            
            <div class="card">
            <h2>Name : User Two</h2>
            <h2>Title : Job Two</h2>
            Enter your name: <input id="tagInput" onkeyup="saveTag(event)"  type="text" placeholder="Comment here" >
            <b>TAG:</b><p class="tagFilter" id="name">tag goes here</p>
            <input onclick="clear()" type="button" value="CLEAR" />
            </div>
      </div>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are setting values with same name, even though they are different values.

You should set values with different names. It can be editted like:

```
function saveTag(event) {
    var tagTerm = event.target.value;
    var tagTextInput = document.querySelectorAll("p.tagFilter");

    tagTextInput.forEach(function (cardTags, itemIndex) {
        localStorage.setItem("tag" + itemIndex, tagTerm);
    });       
}
```

This will save values with individual name, distingiushing indexes by 0,1,2.

## EDIT 2019-09-27

I made some changes to your code, here it is: https://codepen.io/firesped1/pen/ExYJQgy?editors=1010

Before explaining what I did, I have to tell this:

**HTML must not have duplicate IDs.**
It's against the HTML standards, causing errors in ID selectors. If you want to select multiple elements at once, use class or tag selector.

The problem was you were saving the same values to different localStorage keys.I changed the logic to save directly to localStorage.

If you don't have parts that you don't understand, feel free to ask me.

Comment: Hello @YJM, thank you for responding to my plea for help, appreciate it.

Comment: Hello @YJM,  I tried the code you provided on my codepen ( https://codepen.io/marcusnapoleon/pen/GRKzpeE?editors=1111 ) however I lack the understanding to make it work properly for my project.  With your code no data displayed when using the localStorage.getItem. Checking console.log it shows 3 items saved, but each of the tag (tag0, tag1, tag2) contain the comment/tag entered from usercard 3 text input..

Comment: Hello again @YJM, I apologize for my HTML mistakes, I was just copying and pasting to mimic multiple user cards, I was trying to setup api request and it was not working.. now I have array setup like data result from api request..

Comment: https://codepen.io/marcusnapoleon/pen/GRKzpeE      I’m going to look at your new code and will try to understand how I can make it work in my project.

Comment: would you be able to give me direction as to what I need to be learning to accomplish the same task (adding retrieving comments from locals storage per user card/panel) - I’m rendering html from JavaScript.

Comment: I know I have to do some kind of loop and do a function to save to local storage and as well as display, but just can’t figure it out.. Appreciate all your help, Thank you very much, I hope your a patient person, as I might reach out again with more questions, asking for directions..

Comment: Loop doesn't need when you have to save data. You can save data just for the item when you input.

Comment: And if I solved your 'question', can you mark my answer?